# The TURN server turn:xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3479 returned an error with code=701?

Tags: docker, stun, turn, coturn

I have tried setting up a turn server with a database backup of Redis and here's the configurations for the same.

```
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=5349
listening-ip=<my_ip>
realm=<domain_name>
total-quota=100
bps-capacity=100
stale-nonce=600
min-port=49152
max-port=65535
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=<my_auth_key>
server-name=<domain_name>
redis-userdb=<redis_conn_string>
```

And I am testing this server with this :
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
And I get the following error.

```
The server turn:<domain_name>:3479?transport=udp returned an error with code=701:
```

I would like to understand why this happens. Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the STUN/TURN servers are bound to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses otherwise this timeout will occur.